# What triggers the "Trying to get property of non-object" error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf, laravel-exceptions

Since I started with my first Laravel project I've been having the error
`Trying to get property 'column_name' of non-object` nonstop, and most of the time I've been able to fix it one way or another, but the problem is, I have no idea of why I get the error, or how can I prevent it. For example,

```
// In my controller I have this domPDF function...
public function pdfgen(Request $request, $id) {
        $data = Table::find($id);
        View()->share('data', $data);

        if ($request -> has('download')) {
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/pdfgen');
            return $pdf ->download('pdfgen.pdf');
        }

        return view('pdf/pdfgen');
}
```

```
// In my blade file I have a table calling this column...
<td>{{ $data->column }}</td>

// and this link making the request in the pdfgen function... 
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('pdfgen', ['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>
```

```
// And in my routes of web.php...
Route::get('/pdfgen/{id}', array('as' => 'pdfgen', 'uses' => 'PDFController@pdfgen'));
```

and whenever I press that download link, I get a Whoops page with the `trying to get property 'column' of non-object (View: /usr/src/workapp/resources/views/pdf/pdfgen.blade.php)`. Why am I getting this error and not the open/save dialog?

EDIT: Forgot to add, before trying to get specific data with $id, I called the whole table (`$data = Table::all();`) and used a `@foreach` in the blade view to print it in the table

EDIT 2: Adding the model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Table extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        // all columns are strings, even id
        'id',
        'column',
        'column2',
        'column3',
    ];

    public function table2()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Table2');
    }
}
```

Comment: An attempt to address something that IS NOT an object as if it were an Object. Normally because something a little earlier in the code returned an error (normally a boolean) rather than the object it was expected to return. Which means you didnt check for errors

Comment: You'll have to check the documentation to see how to pass the `$data` into `PDF::loadView`. I'm guessing it doesn't get the share from `View::share`

Comment: Are you sure the `$id` exists in the database?

Comment: @Jerodev I made sure I used an `$id` that exists in the table (1234 because it's easy to remember)

Comment: Also I forgot to add that it worked when it didn't have the `$id`, calling all the table and using a `@foreach` to access the data

Comment: @RiggsFolly but how do I know when I'm not passing an object? (besides the error) also to be honest I have no idea how to check for errors

Comment: You check that `$data` returned from this call `$data = Table::find($id);` is not the Error value which I assume will be `false`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Right now the view itself does return the data requested, but when I press the "download" button the error page appears

Comment: What is the exact error message? Namely, which file is causing the error? There are some instances where the document fed to Dompdf can cause this problem (see https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1406) because of how Dompdf is parsing the document.

Comment: I think the problem was with the laravel wrapper I was using (barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) because as soon as I uninstalled that one and installed the normal dompdf the problem went away. (sadly now I have to use html inside a $html variable, but it's better than not being able to go forward) Also I forgot to say I was using a wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `find($id)` and the record is not present, it returns `null`. So if you try to access any property `->column`, it will throw error.

You can either do `findOrFail($id)` **or** have condition `if (is_null($data))` **or** on frontend have `$data->column ?? 'defaultvalue
'`

Now, the second situation where your model is present but you still get error, do  :

```
$data = Table::find($id);
dd(array_keys($data->toArray()));
```

You should see the `column` you are trying to access if it is present.

Lastly, if it is not present in above step but is there in the table, then check for `protected $hidden = []` setting of your model which essentially hides certain columns.

Comment: While trying to fix that problem, I used `$data = Table2::with('Table')->where('id', $id)->get();` and for some reason it works with no problem, but if I use `->first();` instead of `->get();` it returns the `Trying to get property 'column' of non-object` error, why is that?

Comment: Do you have any accessor or an appended property on that model?

Comment: what is an accessor and an appended model?

Comment: [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and [appended properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) :) In short appended property is an additionlal property which is not one of your columns. Like full_name which combo of first and last name. Accessor is a function which modifies the bsic vaue of a column.

Comment: Thanks c:
I think the problem was with the dompdf wrapper I was using (barryvdh/laravel-dompdf, which I forgot to add in the question) because when I uninstalled it and installed the normal version of dompdf the problem stopped appearing (with that particular controller)

Answer (score 0):

This happend because your `$data` might be `null` and your record with given `$id` might not exists in your database.

Try to change your code like below:

```
Table::findOrFail($id);
```

From now on if your table with given id doesn't exist, it'll automatically return `404` page.

Comment: thanks for the fast response, the problem is, that I made sure I chose an ID that I know exists, also yeah, the findOrFail did return the 404

Comment: The problem might be on your model,Put your model code here.

Comment: Try to get access your data with `Table::where('id',$id)->first();` see if that works for you!

Comment: nope, I get the `trying to get property 'column' of non-object` error

Comment: Try to `dd($id)` and check if there is number assigned to it or no!

Comment: ok, I used `dd($id);` and it returned `"1234"` (which is de id I used)